# How to know if my ProcessBuilder start() executed the commands successfully

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm executing a command in java code using `ProcessBuilder` class. Once the `start()` is called I'm done with execution. Every time I run this code, I go to output and verify whether the java code has run the command successfully or not. Question is, will I be able to verify this in the code itself?, instead of verifying my output every time. In future I may not be able to view the output, so I want to make sure my commands run successfully or even if it runs into some exception, I should be able to know it from my code.

`start()` is returning me the `Process` class object and I hardly find any useful methods available under `Process` class.

Code:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(my_command);

String absPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
list.add(absPath);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
Process process = pb.start();
List<String> commandList = pb.command();
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

**Edit:**
Tried `process.exitValue();` but returning me the below error every time I execute my code. Point to note, my output is generated with out any issue even though I see this exception in my console.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.exitValue(ProcessImpl.java:246)
    at com.rwithjava.caller.RWithJavaCaller.processRWithJavaScript(RWithJavaCaller.java:39)
    at com.rwithjava.caller.RWithJavaCaller.main(RWithJavaCaller.java:51)
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue() - exit code?

Comment: Two ways, read the output and parse it and look at the `exitValue` - but you'll have to use `waitFor` to make sure the `Process` has completed

Comment: I tried `pb.wait(5000)` but seems nothing is happening and throwing the error on `exitValue()`

Comment: is it possible that your process is stuck on some loop and not exiting at all?

Comment: @FrancescoRogo Code is not on loop rather a one time execution. Error on `exitValue()` is saying `IllegalThreadStateException` so sensing some code part I'm missing other than `pb.wait(5000)`. My code sequence now is: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
   Process process = pb.start();
   pb.wait(6000);
   System.out.println("exitValue()>>"+process.exitValue());`

Comment: Error is saying "IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited". You can't call exitValue() on a process that is not over, hence the IllegalStateException. For some reason your process doesn't exit gracefully. Try pb.waitFor() after pb.start() instead of pb.wait(6000);

Comment: btw wait() method is an Object.class method, not a Process.class, and is meant to use with notify() methods.

Comment: @FrancescoRogo It works now, I'm able to see the return value as `0` on `exitValue()` after `process.waitFor()` call. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call pb.waitFor, your program will wait for the process to terminate and returns its result code (that should be zero if everything goes well).

If that's not enough, you should capture the standard output and standard error streams and check that you get what you're expecting.

UPDATE

Example code:

```
        Process process = pb.start();
        OutputHandler out
                = new OutputHandler(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        OutputHandler err
                = new OutputHandler(process.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
        int status = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Status: " + status);
        out.join();
        System.out.println("Output:");
        System.out.println(out.getText());
        System.out.println();
        err.join();
        System.out.println("Error:");
        System.out.println(err.getText());
```

Class `OutputHandler`:

```
class OutputHandler extends Thread {
    private final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    private final BufferedReader in;

    OutputHandler(InputStream in, String encoding)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                in, encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding));
        setDaemon(true);
        start();
    }

    String getText() {
        synchronized(buf) {
            return buf.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Reading process output
        try {
            String s = in.readLine();
            while (s != null) {
                synchronized(buf) {
                    buf.append(s);
                    buf.append('\n');
                }
                s = in.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried `pb.wait(5000)` but seems nothing is happening and throwing the error on `exitValue()`

Comment: @mannedear either 5000 isn't enough, or you're not consuming the output/error streams.

Comment: `you're not consuming the output/error streams` I'm sure not doing anything with output/error streams as I have no idea what they can do.

Comment: It works now, I'm able to see the return value as `0` on `exitValue()` after `process.waitFor()` call. Thanks a ton Maurice!

Comment: FYI, I'm still not consuming the output/error streams.